# Linear Algebra, Bases, Dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

- Choose a basis of a vector subspace and extend it to a basis of a vector space
- State dimensions of a vector subspace and a vector space

a)$W =\{(a,b,c) :  a+b+c=0 , 2a+b−c=0\}$, $V =\{(a,b,c); a+b+c=0\}$

Anyone know how I would go about to solving this question?

Answer (score 0):

For $W$, from your first equation, you obtain that $a=-b-c$.

From your second equation you obtain $c= 2a +b$ and if you replace in your first equation,

$a=-b-2a-b$ which implies $3a=-2b$ or $a=\frac{-2}{3}b$. And replacing this value in your equation for $c$ you obtain $c= \frac{-4}{3}b +b = \frac{-1}{3}b$

And therefore any $w \in W$ is of the form $w = (\frac{-2}{3}b,b,\frac{-1}{3}b)=b(\frac{-2}{3},1,\frac{-1}{3})$ with $b \in \Bbb{R}$.

So $W = span (\frac{-2}{3},1,\frac{-1}{3})$ and therefore, $\operatorname{dim}(W)=1$.

To extend your base of $W$ (which is $\{(\frac{-2}{3},1,\frac{-1}{3})\}$) to a base of $\Bbb{R}^3$ you have to add, to linearly independent vectors. For example, $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ you can check that they are linearly independant.

Can you try doing the same for $V$? (Hint, $\dim (V) = 2$)

Comment: Thank you so much!
for the w=(−4/3b,b,−1/3b)=b(−4/3,1,−1/3), shouldn't it be -2/3b since a=-2/3b?

Comment: Absolutely, already edited.